# MySQL database structure Composite entities model

Tags: mysql, database, entity

I am trying to create a MySQL database which holds the information of users, movies and information relating the the movies set by each user. I currently have it setup as a composite entity (I think) but am unsure if this is correct or the best approach. I have written out the headings for each table below to make more sense.

User_ID / Username / ect

Movie_ID / Movie_Desc / Movie_Length

Composite entity:  User_ID / Movie_ID / Personal rating /

Currently the composite entity holds repeated data, repeating the user_id multiple times which is linking to different movies.

Is there a better approach i can take to store this type of information? I cant figure a way out that minimises the repeated data.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you letting multiple users rate multiple movies? Like User A can Rate Movie M and Movie N also, User B can rate Movie M and Movie N? If so, what you are doing is the best approach available. Just maintain foreign key relationships if you want to expedite the query execution.

Comment: It's unlikely that the rating itself would form part of that composite. But apart from that, there's no repetition here.

Comment: Yes every user should be able to rate every movie, thanks for your reply:)